# Convert bytes32 to bytes

Tags: solidity, remix, data-types

Is there a simple way to convert `bytes32` to `bytes` in Solidity?

I'm trying to get the length of the string passed in the bytes32 variable but everything gets returned 32 size which makes sense.

But explicit conversion does not seem to work:

```
bytes memory _tmpUsername = bytes(_username);  // _username is of type bytes32
```

This throws an error of:

```
Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "bytes storage pointer"
```

Answer (score 19):

Since `solidity@0.4.22`, you can use `abi.encodePacked()` for this, which returns `bytes`. For example ;

```
contract C { 
  function toBytes(bytes32 _data) public pure returns (bytes) {
    return abi.encodePacked(_data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a totally inefficient method of converting bytes32 to bytes (while removing extra zeros bytes to the right).

```
function bytes32ToBytes(bytes32 data) internal pure returns (bytes) {
    uint i = 0;
    while (i < 32 && uint(data[i]) != 0) {
        ++i;
    }
    bytes memory result = new bytes(i);
    i = 0;
    while (i < 32 && data[i] != 0) {
        result[i] = data[i];
        ++i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I actually was thinking on similar lines but wouldn't it be a problem if my data contains a 0 in its value? Say for example - data is "test2010"?

Comment: The zero digit '0' has a value of 48 when considered as a byte, so it should not be a problem (this applies to more common string encoding, ASCII, UTF-8).

Answer (score 4):

### Answer for Solidity v0.8.4 and above

You can use `bytes.concat` instead of `abi.encodePacked`.

```
function toBytes(bytes32 data) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
    return bytes.concat(data);
}
```

My understanding is that `bytes.concat` will ultimately replace `abi.encodePacked`.

Answer (score 1):

Using inline assembly you can copy a `bytes32` to a `bytes` structure like this:

```
  function bytes32ToBytes(bytes32 input) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
    bytes memory b = new bytes(32);
    assembly {
      mstore(add(b, 32), input) // set the bytes data
    }
    return b;
  }
```